# How to speed up a HP M9517C

Tags: performance, graphics-card

I bought a system with 8GB RAM, 1TB HD, Quad-Core AMD Phenom 9550, Nvidia Geforce 9300GE, 64-bit Windows Vista Machine.

Bought it primarily because it was cheap and came with 25.5 inch screen.

Problem: It's slow - if you can believe it. My Dell laptop 1525 is faster and more stable!

I tried installing and dual-booting Linux Mint and ran into video and audio troubles.

I need fast and stable and I'm going for awesome.

Anyone have some suggestions on making this thing smoking hot? Vista is fine, but slows over time - suspect virus/spyware/etc.. But I need to use Photoshop, Fireworks, Dreamweaver, Illustrator. I've tried the alternatives and I just don't like them. When you've got deadlines looming you want to work with what you know. Also use Skype (and I had audio problems with it in Linux), gotomeeting, gotowebinar. Don't need MS Office. Tried VMWare, Virtualbox and again - I keep getting audio/video problems.

I'd love someone's input on THEIR setup and how they got there.

I'm sure I need to upgrade my video card, but what should I go to?

Answer (score 1):

hang in there for a wee while and wait for Windows 7 x64

or get it now for a [free 90 days test drive](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Molly, and also think the machine needs to be reformatted and re-installed properly. Ensure you have the correct 64-Bit drivers for all the hardware, and make sure you run either [Avast](http://www.avast.com) Home Edition or [AVG](http://www.avg.com) as Anti-Virus.

Also check the if the machine is getting sufficient cooling and that the PSU is powerful enough to drive it, especially considering the 25" LCD.

It really sound like a hardware driver issue somewhere along the line, or otherwise a bad combination of hardware components.

Comment: i'd give you a vote, but i have difficulties to endorse AVG, their most unkosher link checker and the installation of a browser searchbar are inacceptable for me (i know these 'features' can be disabled, but they are the default settings, not good).

Comment: I personally don't use it either, I prefer Avast and dislike AVG. However most people recommend it so I added it for safety sake.

Comment: this i will accept as an excuse :) +1

Comment: Molly: Most security suites will install a browser toolbar for you.

Comment: @joshhunt. Strangely Avast doesn't. It is the one reason a love it.